# Solving sub-matrix preserving overall linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a linear system

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} \ A_{12} \ A_{13}\\
A_{21} \ A_{22} \ A_{23}\\
A_{31} \ A_{32} \ A_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which comes from the discretization of a system of PDEs. The overall system is large, non-symmetric and contains a saddle point problem.

Let's assume I know something about the sub-matrix $A_{2,2}$, which I can use to solve the sub-matrix more efficient. For example $A_{2,2}$ might be a diagonal matrix or symmetric or I have a suitable pre-conditioner for it.

What can I do with this knowledge. Can I precondition or even solve $A_{2,2}$ (replacing $A_{2,2}$ by $I$ and adjusting $b_2$)? How does this affect the other parts of the matrix or the right hand side?

*Edit:* Additional ideas: $A_{ij}$ for $i\ne j$ (non-diagonal blocks) are very sparse and are only for coupling the systems of equations. Can there be made a connection to Block Jacobi methods / preconditioning which kind of tries the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic preconditioner for 
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} \ A_{12} \ A_{13}\\
A_{21} \ A_{22} \ A_{23}\\
A_{31} \ A_{32} \ A_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
is a Jacobi (or diagonal) preconditioner, i.e. $\mathrm{diag}(A)$. 
Now if you have suitable pre-conditioner for $A_{22}$, say $P_{22}$, then I would try to use the following preconditioner 
$$P=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{diag}(A_{11}) & 0 & 0\\
0 &P_{22} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{diag}( A_{33})\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

If your matrix is block n-diagonal, then I would suggest to read [the following thing](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0377042785900044/1-s2.0-0377042785900044-main.pdf?_tid=45cc2e46-95b6-11e5-89e0-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1448704759_2d697e4ac9e67887ab5b25158e87e050). I didn't read it all, the name is block-matrix preconditioning, but at first pages looks like they talking about a block 3-diagonal. Perhaps later they generalize it. For a PDE discretization you get such matrices, so hopefully this is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm giving you bad news, but what you in fact have is this (where obviously $A_{jk}$ are block matrices):
$$A_{11}x_{1}+A_{12}x_{2}+A_{13}x_{3}=b_{1}$$
$$A_{21}x_{1}+A_{22}x_{2}+A_{23}x_{3}=b_{2}$$
$$A_{31}x_{1}+A_{32}x_{2}+A_{33}x_{3}=b_{3}$$
Now...unfortunately if you don't have any other restriction I guess that's as far as you can get. If you other symmetries maybe you can go further. The fact that you solved the block matrix $A_{22}=b_2$ unfortunately doesn't help you much. Indeed is more or less like knowing that $y=7$ doesn't help you in find $x,z$ in the equation $$x+y+z=7$$
I'm sorry but I hope this answer was anyway useful telling to look other directions...

Comment: You are right, I don't like this :-) I know that off diagonal blocks have very few entries.

Comment: Well, if you have really few entries may be they could be rearranged to have $A_{21}$ and $A_{32}=0$, in that case the solution You have might result effectively useful. Otherwise if the coefficient of the matrix $A_{21}$ and $A_{32}=0$ are few and low in norm you can eliminate them, get an aproximated the solution and after work out the original one. If the answer was useful please click the upper row.